# Is it possible with shiny to make the label appear when hovering over a line?

Tags: r, plot, hover, shiny

As shown [here](https://plot.ly/python/time-series/)

This is useful when there are multiple lines and unreadable legend..

Comment: Link not accessible for me.

Comment: can't manage to give you a working link, but it doesn't really make the question less interesting so thanks for the -1...

Comment: I did not give you the -1. But I guess the person gave the minus one not to for the link not working, they would only post a comment, but because the link is all the information you put in the question.

Comment: ok sorry then. Well my question didn't require any more details but I found the answer myself so I added it for people who might not know this package as well. Thanks for answering anyway !

Comment: I definitely think it is a valid contribution though reformulating the question a little bit and removing "thank you" would help.

Comment: Though there question should be a little reformulated so that it is a question. Also removing the "thank you" mail help

Comment: ok thank you for the reformulation (I wonder why say thank you is penalizing but ok :-) !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77126/discussion-between-cmbarbu-and-stephanie-c).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like rChart will do the job ! A useful demo [here](http://ramnathv.github.io/rChartsShiny/)

Comment: Put the link in your answer (edit it) and remove the comment